# neo4j Remote guide error neo4j TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: neo4j

I try to write my own neo4j-guide as described [at neo4j](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-create-neo4j-browser-guide/).

Neither my own example nor the included restaurant_recommendation.html seems to work. If I call in chrome http://localhost:8080/play/html/restaurant_recommendation.html I get a clean page.

If I call :play http://localhost:8080/play/html/restaurant_recommendation.html I get

```
Remote guide error
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Any suggestion what's wrong or how to analyze it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the cors. So I installed a chrome-plugin [CORS_TOGGLE](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwimxL_F3c7UAhXLbVAKHVIpBcgQFghEMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fcors-toggle%2Fomcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh&usg=AFQjCNHc-a-zE5yyw_5SXMazDSdE3PSwjw&sig2=IY37g_PeE3_bS1q4zVbjtA) which solves the problem for me.